# msiexec can‘t install package which use https

Tags: windows-installer

```
msiexec /qn /i "https://172.0.1.125:8443/api/v1/package/566e56d3474acdafe1ef680a /log c:\windows\temp\csb_package_setup.log CUSTOMER_ID=565d5d688b8604506da815d3 SERVER_ADDRESS=https://172.0.1.125:8443"

msiexec /qn /i "http://172.0.1.125:8080/api/v1/package/566e56d3474acdafe1ef680a /log c:\windows\temp\csb_package_setup.log CUSTOMER_ID=565d5d688b8604506da815d3 SERVER_ADDRESS=http://172.0.1.125:8080"
```

The first command line can't execute (HTTPS), the second executes successfully (HTTP).

What's the problem? Do I need to install a certificate?

Comment: Probably, just open the https ,ip, and port part in IE, download the certificate and mark it as trusted

Comment: Why are there spaces in the protocol part of the URL? And can you access the URL from your browser?

Comment: Yes ,because i need to download the package from a server .I can download the package use broswer.But when i use the cmd ,it cannot work .

Comment: @Martheen I have download the certificate and mark it ad trusted .When i execute the command ,it still doesn't work

Comment: @DirkVollmar it's a shame ,i am a new guy who use stackover flow ,i come from China .I can't paste url in a question because i have not enough repution.

Comment: What do your log files indicate failed?

Comment: @MichaelUrman Thanks ,I'll check it

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit, I've never researched what MSI does / doesn't support (or put another way what works well and what doesn't ) with regard to installing from a webserver.  I can't imagine I'm missing much because I've never seen anyone use it so if it works it probably doesn't work well.

What I do see a lot of is people using EXE bootstrapper / chainers to download the MSI and cache it before installing.  For InstallShield this is setup prerequisites and suite installers, for WiX this is Burn.  It would be very easy to take some random MSI and create a web enabled WiX bootstrapper that does as I previously described.   That is the direction I would go.

Comment: @MichaelUrman - Do you have any thoughts on installing from a URI?  Is there more to it and better then support that I'm assuming?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: I don't know. I would expect msiexec leverages fairly standard internet support code, but https introduces additional failure cases (bad cert, untrusted cert, etc.) and doesn't seem to offer any way to select the behavior. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368328.aspx) claims XP/2003+ support https. Regardless, behavior on any failure sucks from a raw `mseixec /i <url>` call, so agreed with using a bootstrapper.